# Is it possible to put laravel project on outside of Document root?

Tags: php, laravel, centos7

Where should I put a larval project on server directory?
I put my larval file ~/[larave_project_name]

DocumentRoot is /var/www/html/.
I moved public/index.php  into DocumenRoot.
But I found In DocumentRoot, Those files can’t load files from outside of var/www

My Server environment is Cent OS7 / Apache 2.4 /PHP 7.4

Answer (score 1):

The intent is for the webserver to have a document root of the public directory within your laravel project.

A good starting point would be:

1. Move the files from `~/[laravel_project_name]` to `/var/www/[laravel_project_name]`
2. Update the default for the web server configuration to change the document root from `/var/www/html` to `/var/www/[laravel_project_name]/public`

Comment: Here's also a rather useful link to the [relevant section](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/structure#the-public-directory) of Laravel 10.x documentation.